# R Split sentence based on pattern

Tags: r, gsub

I need to split a sentence base on address patter. Below is a reproducible sample of the problem I'm facing.

```
 s <- c("Junipero Sierra Room 9001 coals ave","patio room2200 virginia beach ave")
```

Currently, this is what I'm using

```
  gsub(".*([A-z]{1,}[0-9]{2,6})|.*([A-z]{1,} [0-9]{2,6})", "\\1",s)
```

This is what I get,

```
 [1] " coals ave"               "m2200 virginia beach ave"
```

but this is what I want

```
[1] "9001 coals ave"         "2200 virginia beach ave"
```

Comment: Your example doesn't help generalize the problem. Maybe describe in words what you expect the splitting to do. How would this work with other strings?

Comment: Try [`sub(".*?(\\d{4})", "\\1", s)`](http://rextester.com/VWGTPX9918). BTW, what is the logic behind your regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to cut off everything before `[0-9]{2,6}`:

```
> gsub(".*?([0-9]{2,6})", "\\1", s)
[1] "9001 coals ave"          "2200 virginia beach ave"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s <- c("Junipero Sierra Room 9001 coals ave","patio room2200 virginia beach ave")
get.String=function(x){
  sx=unlist(strsplit(x,""))
  st=grep("[0-9]",sx)[1]
  x=substring(x,st,nchar(x))
  return(x)
}
sapply(s,get.String)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.